Google play store App rejected, how do I edit it?
How to fix these issues? I don't see any field where I can change the video or edit my app submission? I submitted my app to the apple app store before and it was easy to edit my submission, but I'm struggling to find it on the google play console. Thank you.


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Please share the actual rejection email
